# Spring Data Mongo - Update multiple records

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I need to update multiple records. I cannot perform **bulk** update query by criteria, because we have a rule that for each db change we have to send a message to message broker. Therefore, I will need to **update entities one by one**.

I use Spring Data Repository. I can do it either by making pageable requests and updating elements in pages.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories

```
@Service
class MyEntityService {
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, ObjectId>

    updateMultipleEntities(UpdateRules updateRules) {
        Criteria criteria = buildCriteria(updateRules);
        long totalrecords = myEntityRepository.count(criteria);
        long totalUpdateCound = 0;

        // LET US ASSUME THAT NUMBER OF RECORDS DOES NOT CHANGE

        while (totalUpdateCound < totalrecords) {
            Page page = myEntityRepository.findAll(buildPageble(totalUpdateCound, criteria));
            processElementsFromPage(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to stream all elements an update them. It looks easier.

```
@Service
class MyEntityService {
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, ObjectId>

    updateMultipleEntities(UpdateRules updateRules) {
        Criteria criteria = buildCriteria(updateRules);
     
        // LET US ASSUME THAT NUMBER OF RECORDS DOES NOT CHANGE
        myEntityRepository.streamAll(criteria).forEach(element -> processElement(element, updateRules));
        
    }
}
```

Are there drawbacks with solution that uses `streamAll(criteria)`? As I understand, it would be useful to use pageable requests if I need to have pagination on the UI.  However, how about my case where I need to process elements one by one.

## Update

http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html

Example why streaming results can improve performance. However, it shows only **read-only** cases.

Comment: The performance difference of the two methods of iterating through your query results are going to be insignificant compared to how slow it's going to be updating records one at a time. Also note that the "read-only" stream example you linked applies to your case because the stream you are using would still be "read-only". It's not like you would be pushing updates into the stream, you would be pushing updates directly to the database.